# Subring of intergers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \quad d> 0, d \neq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for $d> 0, d \neq 1$. It can easily be shown that they are
$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}] \quad \text{if} \quad d\equiv2,3 \pmod4$$
$$\mathbb Z \left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2} \right] \quad \text{if} \quad d\equiv1 \pmod4.$$
Also it can be shown that algebraic integers form a ring. I tried to find subrings of that ring.

My first approach was to find all rings that are generated by only one element, and than two, three ... So I Googled it and found that you can generate most subrings by two elements.

Is there way to show that a subring generated by three elements can also be generated at most two elements?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675307/in-the-ring-of-integers-of-mathbb-q-sqrt-d-if-every-non-zero-ideal-a-is).

Comment: @David what do you mean by generated? Generated additively (as a  group) or generated by adding and multiplying (as a ring)? As a ring all subrings of rings of integers of quadratic fields are generated by just one element, this property is known as being monogenic.

Comment: I only edited this question, so you may wish to ask @josf

Comment: @AlexJBest enerated by adding and multiplying (as a ring)

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ by $\mathcal{O}_K$. 
Recall that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank 2. Now any subring $R\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ has to contain $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence can be viewed as a submodule of $\mathcal{O}_K$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, $R$ is also a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank at most 2 and $R$ can be generated by 2 generators as a module.